# Android: Back button press while AsyncTask is running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an `ActivityA`, which has a Button. Upon Click on the `button`, it opens up another `ActivityB`.

`onCreate()` method of `ActivityB`, I am starting `AsyncTask` which connect to server and fetch the results and display it to the screen.

Here is the Code of `Activity B`:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    AsyncFetch asyncFetch;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(null != savedInstanceState) {
            return;
        }
        asyncFetch = new AsyncFetch();
        asyncFetch.execute();
    }
}


private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        //contacts the http server.
    }
}
```

While executing `AsyncFetch`, when I hit back press, the `ActivityB` is not getting destroyed immediately. But gets destroyed after `AsyncTask` gets completed.

How do I implement this to avoid back press freeze? I tried below:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    asyncFetch.cancel(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

But still it waits the `AsyncTask` to cancel or complete.

Like `GMail` app, when I open something. While in the process if I press back button, it just comes out of that `Activity`.

Is there any other way of implementing background process? Any `design pattern` to implement this? Please let me know.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: will you be needing that response from the server even if backkey is pressed??

Comment: AsyncTasks do not block the UI thread if implemented correctly. Post your full code.

Comment: UI is not getting blocked. but the Activity is not getting destroyed till async is completed.

Comment: Than how you experience the "back press freeze"?

Comment: I experienced, the activity is not getting closed till the Async is completed.

Comment: How did you solved this?? I'm facing same, all the answers below are not working for me

Answer (score 4):

Just handle yourself the onBackPressed() method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (asyncFetch != null)
        asyncFetch.cancel(true);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the android developer's [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> Cancelling a task
>
> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible (inside a loop for instance.)

So in short, you can mark the `AsyncTask` as cancelled in `onPause()` or `onBackPressed()` from your `Activity`, and then you can add a few if blocks in `doInBackground()` and return right away if task is cancelled.

For example:

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground(Object... params){

    // do some work

    if(isCancelled()){
        // end task right away
        return null;
    }
    // if task is not cancelled yet,
    // do some other work
}
```

However, if the network operation has already started, you will need to cancel it from your `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    asyncFetch.cancel(true);
    // If you want to finish the activity you can use below code
    // finish(); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the same as well but still behavior same.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go. Try this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (asyncFetch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
       asyncFetch.cancel(true);
    } 
    finish(); 
}
```

Comment: are u sure u tried the same without the super.onBackPressed(); in the starting?

Comment: I tried the same, but still I see the issue. FYI, what I am doing in AsyncTast is HTTP communication. I am connecting to server through HTTPClient. While in the process of http, the back press just wait on finish() method till the async task get close.

Answer (score -1):

When you `click` the back `button`, it will firstly called `onBackPressed()`, so in this part, cancel the `asynctask`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if ( asyncFetch != null && asyncFetch.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING ){
       asyncFetch.cancel(true);
    } 
}
```